# Firebase - Offline behaviour for Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, offline

I recently started working on my game using Firebase and considering what Firebase offers is pretty much all I need, at one place. But now i'm facing few limitations/implementation issues so any help would be appreciated.

I'm developing a semi-online game which will allow users to play as long as no network is available and sync with Firebase soon as it gets connected. For very first launch connection is mandatory as i've to pull configuration data from Firebase and later user can play with offline **saved state** which will be pushed later whenever connected.

I'm quite noob to Firebase so pardon me if I misunderstood any implementation. I looked over different answers and mostly were in respect to native Android/iOS, not for Unity. So either I wasn't able to find my answer or it was asked years ago but still not answered. Thanks!

Comment: I believe Firebase still does not support offline mode with Unity. I could be wrong

Comment: @StuckBetweenTrees thank you for your support and I believe you are right. Because I've been searching long for the possible solution and still couldn't find one. Maybe I have to move off eventually after so much work already done and expectation on Firebase.

Comment: But I do not see why would you need one. You are stating that people will be able to play offline and once they get online data will be sync. Why cant you do it manually? Have a look here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27536480/how-to-store-game-data-without-an-online-database

Comment: I had a thought I might need to do this manually but problem then arise is maintaining whole lot of data (user state, metadata etc) would be bit of a hassle. Saving and retrieving isn't a problem but I've to check manually which version of data is updated and must push _OR_ pull as per need. I do believe that I've to do that eventually but I was looking for quick workaround if already provided by Firebase guys.Thanks for the help though (: much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Disk persistence for the Realtime Database is now available since version 5.4.0 of the Firebase SDK for Unity. See the documentation for [`FirebaseDatabase. SetPersistenceEnabled()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/firebase-database#setpersistenceenabled) and the [release notes for that version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#5.4.0).

Comment: Does Firestore support offline mode in Unity, or just the Realtime Database.  Firebase recommends using Firestore over the Realtime Database for new projects.

Comment: "Firebase recommends using Firestore over the Realtime Database for new projects." Nope, it doesn't (check my credentials to understand why I can say that with such certainty). Each database has its own strengths and weaknesses, and which one to use depends on your project. The [database recommender](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) in the documentation is typically the best place to strt.

Comment: I am aware of your credentials :-) I am referring to the Realtime Database section at https://firebase.google.com/products:  "Realtime Database is Firebase's original database. It's an efficient, low-latency solution for mobile apps that require synced states across clients in realtime. We recommend Cloud Firestore instead of Realtime Database for most developers starting a new project."

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've filed a bug to get it updated, as it's simply not true anymore. We've found that both databases have their own strengths, and have since updated most documentation, and updated the database recommender to cover the most common use-cases/

Comment: Do you know if Firestore supports offline mode (while the app is not running) in Unity?

Comment: I thought it did, but couldn't find a document link for it when I saw your comment. I'd recommend opening a new question for it though, as it's unlikely anyone but me will see the comment here anytime soon.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but still hard to find a correct answer. 
Firebase documentation is definitively ambiguous : on this page : 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start 
First lines : 
"The Firebase Realtime Database stores and synchronizes data with our NoSQL cloud database. Data is synced across all clients in realtime, and remains available when your app goes offline."

Unity Firebase does not support real offline capabilities.
It will work only if your game starts with a network ON, and while playing, if the player has network OFF, it will go on correctly **as long as you have the network ON before stopping the game !** so it can synchronize.. otherwise all changes are lost !

Here is a answer coming from the firebase support on this problem :

> Currently, Unity doesn't support offline capability. Apologies about this. This is indeed something we're looking into, however, I cannot guarantee that this will be available anytime soon. We'll keep your feedback in consideration moving forward.
>
> The documentation is explaining that your app will continue to save your data while offline. When data is written, it's written to this local version first and synchronizes that data to the server once connectivity is reestablished. Check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#write_data_offline) for more details. For additional context, Firebase's network resilience will work on Unity. So as long as the app stays active, Firebase will continue functioning if the network connection drops. In that case it serves any reads from its cache and keeps a queue of pending writes. But currently there is no support for disk persistence, which would allow the cache and queue to survive during app restarts.

Answer (score 1):

I activated

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

during initialization of my game.
It works fine in iOS but it does not work in Android.